# Observables with arguments in Angular 5

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to Angular 5 and I had a question I was hoping someone could help with.

I have a `Parent` component and a `Child` component. `Parent` passes an  `Action` object into the `Child` component.

*in parent.component.html:*

`<child [action]="someAction"></child>`

The `Action` class has a method `doSomething(arg: string)` which should return an Observable that the `Child` can subscribe to. I want the `Child` component to be able to do the following:

`action.doSomething("some arg passed in by the child").subscribe(//the usual next, error, and complete callbacks)`

**Essentially what I want is what angular/common/http's `http.get(url)` does. It takes an argument and returns an observable. That's exactly what I want to do.**

The `doSomething(arg)` method could do something like make an `http.post(..)` call for example. But I don't want to have the child make the `http.post(..)` call directly if I can avoid it. I want the child component to be reusable in that it simply invokes `doSomething(..)` and the parent defines what `doSomething(..)` should actually do.

The child is *not* interested in what `doSomething(..)` returns. It simply wants to know if `doSomething(..)` call succeeded or failed.

How would the method `doSomething(..)` look? **How would I create the Observable to return?** Actual code examples would be appreciated.

I cannot just pass a callback from parent to child because the child needs to know if the call succeeded or failed.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you could us map to check success and return the result as new Observable

Answer (score 0):

Next time, you should show all `methods`, `variables` that are in the context of the question. In this case, `doSomething()`. What does it do? what does it return?

Nonetheless, you should turn to `Service`. The `action` from **Parent** is not necessarily the same as `action` in **Child**. It is mutable. You operate on Child's `action` doesn't affect the `action` in **Parent** at all.

Hence, what does `doSomething` return? and does the **Child** interest in the value retuned by `doSomething`?

If yes, you should use `Service`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edited my question to provide more context.

Comment: I’ve tested/played around with it. Like I thought you wanted to call HttpRequest in doSomething() but somehow the Child component will not be aware of this.http (in Parent) when Child calls doSomething to subscribe.

Comment: @coffeeeee https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obs-parent-child here's a stackblitz I played with. If you inject `HttpClient` in your Child then pass the injected `HttpClient` up to `doSomething()` on Parent and use that passed-http to call `get` then it works. I hope you can make use of this and tweak it

Comment: The problem is that I don't want child to be aware of what the parent wants to do. So I don't want the child to even know about any http calls.

Essentially what I want is what angular/common/http's ``http.get(url)`` does. It takes an argument and returns an observable. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Then you're making things complicated. Do you wanna call `doSomething()` from Child or not? If not, and as you stated, you only wanna know from Child if the call in Parent succeeded or not, you just have to have another @Input and set the input to true/false based on the result of the call from Parent.

Comment: I agree with Chau's answer, a service is best suited for what you're trying to accomplish. Best for sharing data with your components, and you will not have the issue where a child component can't update the parent or vice and versa.